# How does gaining Hero Experience work?

Tags: dota-2

Could you explain in detail when my hero does and does not get experience?

- **killing**

  - I assume I get experience for everything I kill with my bare hands. Including global skills (like natures prophet)
- **minions**

  - Everything that gets killed by an minion of mine. (chen, enchantress, broodmother, ..) gives me xp, no matter how far away my hero is (or if he is alive)
- **creeps**

  - Do I get experience for enemy creeps killed by my creeps? Or do I have to assist the kill to get experience?
  - What is the experience radius? I often read about keeping the enemy away from creep xp, how far do I have to push them back? what about denies?
- **turrets**

  - Do I get anything from kills by turret?
- **heroes**

  - How much experience do I get for a kill and / or assist? Do I have to be in "experience range" to get assist experience?
- **being dead**

  - Does this unique state has any influence on getting experience from minions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Dota 2 wiki](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Experience):

> Experience in DotA 2 is given by a unit on the enemy team that dies.
>
> - Experience is equally shared by all allied heroes in a 1500 range.
> - Hero kills outside of 1500 range will give experience to the killer. (I.e. Sniper's *Assassinate*, Invoker's *Sun Strike*, Zeus' *Thundergod's Wrath* or any summoned unit - Lone Druid's *Spirit Bear*, Nature Prophet's *Treants*, Broodmother's *Spiderling* and *Spiderite*)
> - Denying an allied Hero does not grant experience to the enemy.
> - Denying lane creeps grants 25% of their usual experience to both the enemy and the ally.
> - Denying a player-controlled unit does not grant experience to the enemy or the ally.
> - Neutrals killing lane creeps is considered the same as the enemy creeps killing them—it's not a deny, and gives full XP. You must deny the creep yourself to deny its XP.
> - Neutral creep deaths grant experience to any nearby hero, regardless of the team that gets the last hit.
> - Heroes take their share of experience even after level 25, even though they cannot use it.
> - Observer Wards grant 100 experience when killed
> - Ancients and Roshan acts as Neutral creeps with shared experience to all heroes within 1500 radius
> - Bounty Rune grants experience to the hero that activates the rune (25 base exp + 7 exp/min)
> - Hand of Midas active ability grants 185% of the transmuted creep's experience bounty to the hero that activates the item
> - Tome of Knowledge active ability grants 500 exp to the hero that activates the item plus an additional 135 exp for each tome used by the team.

Comment: Not sure if you get experience if you die prior to being credited the kill. I'm actually pretty confident that you don't, because it's widely held that trading a kill for a kill in solo lane situations is beneficial if your opponent dies first. Needs to be tested. =o

Comment: I'm a bit confused with deny XP. I was under the impression that when you denied a creep (or hero too I guess) you (and allies) gained xp, and the enemy got nothing. It sounds like no-one gets XP from that dot point.

Comment: @Dracs nope, denying creeps significantly reduces their xp, but you don't steal it

Comment: @Decency Pretty sure you don't get experience if you're dead except when you have a Bloodstone, as mentioned above. I think you do get experience if it is a simultaneous death though, unless Techies suicide is a special case.

Comment: Does last hitting gain you any _bonus_ xp?

Comment: @ChrisRasys no, just bonus gold

Comment: What about creeps slain while your hero is far away? For example, creeps under your control killing enemy creeps in a different lane. Or, batrider's firefly killing creeps after batrider has already left the area. You clearly get the gold from those creeps slain, but do you get the xp in those situations?

Answer (score 4):

Its important to note that if the hero is under the [hex](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Hex)(Sheep) effect they gain no experience.

Answer (score 1):

Lich's *Sacrifice* ability will also grant experience to Lich and any ally within AOE.

From the [Dota 2 wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Lich):

> Does not deny the target unit. All allied heroes within the experience range
>   will get experience from the unit killed by Sacrifice.

*Note: updated in Patch 6.85, Sacrifice no longer splits experience with enemies*